# Android Room storing a date and optional time

Tags: java, android, datetime

I am building a simple todo app which will allow a user to append a deadline to a todo. I want users to be able to either only choose a date (make it an 'all-day task' sort of), or pick both a date and a time for when the todo should be finished.

Some research told me using 1 column in the database for a `LocalDate` and 1 column for a `LocalTime` would be unwise due to timezone issues.

Now I've thought up the following:

- 1 column will contain a `LocalDate` (as a string ofcourse) and the other an `Instant` (as a Long).
- If a user only defines a date, it will be stored in the `LocalDate` column and the `Instant` column will be null.
- If a user defines both a date and time, it will be stored as an `Instant` and the `LocalDate` column will be null.

This, however, really feels like a sloppy solution. Are there any alternatives? Should I use 2 different todo tables - one for an all day task and another for a date and time task?

Comment: `only choose a date (make it an 'all-day task' sort of), or pick both a date and a time` save the date and time into a Date object, with a boolean flag for `isAllDayTask`. if it's true, use only the date, else use the date + time

Comment: I've thought about that, but what if it is an all-day task with time set at 00:00 for convenience and someone changes time zone. All of a sudden the time shifts forwards or backwards an hour which causes the date to change as well, whereas that shouldn't have happened.